# Disable Specific USBs with the Terminal?

Tags: usb

I need to disable one specific usb device one way or another with the terminal, disabling the device itself or disabling the usb at which said device it's connected

Also a way to enable them again

I've tried this but it doesn't seem work on my raspberry pi 4: https://askubuntu.com/questions/741760/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-a-specific-usb-port-so-it-doesnt-accept-any-device

Help please

Comment: the link you provided lead to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux/12675749#12675749

Comment: I have been using the following manually switchable USB3 hub for a couple of years and found it good. References: (1) https://store.insite.co.nz/orico-4-port-usb-3-0-hub-black.html. Perhaps you can hack the manual switches and make them Rpi GPIO friendly, ie, no newbie scary, always messing up linux stuff. :)

Comment: *disabling the device itself* depends on what the device is

Comment: You can also check [my answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99156/detecting-device-path-for-usb-scanner/) if you want